# Python: Looping with Tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter

So basically what I want is that when I press a button a certain image will continuously run from one end to another. I have tried many possible ways of doing that but when i put the image into any kind of loop it just wont move anymore and when I give it the coordinates with rand x, y it moves, but disappears from the screen after a while.
Here is the code with the latest loop example:

```
def Start():
    global root
    root = Tk()
    background = PhotoImage(file= "trees.png")
    width1 = background.width()
    height1 = background.height()
    global canvas, taust_i
    canvas = Canvas(width=width1, height=height1)
    canvas.pack()
    x = (width1)/2
    y = (height1)/2
    background_i = canvas.create_image(x, y, image=background) 
    button(root)
    root.mainloop()

def button(root):
    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.pack()
    button1 = Button(frame, text = "Rain", command = Rain, fg = "red" )
    button1.pack(side = LEFT)

def Rain():
    global drops_background
    global drops
    counter = 0
    filename = "Drops.png"
    drops = PhotoImage(file=filename)
    drops_background = canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=drops)
    root.after(100, Move) 

def Move():
    global drops_background
    for i in range(4):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            x = 100
            y = 100
        else:
            y = -100
            x = -100
            i = 2
        canvas.move(drops_background, x, y)
        root.after(250, Move)
```

I also tried placing the image back to the top corner(with drops_background.place(x = 10, y = 10)) but for some reason it decides not to work.
If anyone could tell me what am i doing wrong or how can I loop the image then I would be really thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the image is moved 4 times and "Move" is called again 4 times every time the Move() function is executed, so you get 4*4*4*4*4 etc and will soon slow down the computer

```
for i in range(4):
    ... code ommitted
    canvas.move(drops_background, x, y)
    root.after(250, Move)
```

It is a bad habit to use i, l, or o as single digit variable names as they can look like numbers.  Also the Python Styleguide uses CamelCase for class names and lower_case_with_underlines for function and variable names https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ which means others can read and understand your code better.

This program moves a ball, but an image can be substituted on the canvas, and is preferred to trying to debug your somewhat confusing code and it's use of globals.

```
from Tkinter import *

class BounceTest():
    def __init__(self):
        self.running=True
        self.window = Tk()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.window, width = 400, height = 300)
        self.canvas.grid()

        self.x0 = 10
        self.y0 = 50
        self.x1 = 60
        self.y1 = 100
        self.deltax = 2
        self.deltay = 3
        which=self.canvas.create_oval(self.x0, self.y0, self.x1, self.y1,
                                      fill="red", tag='red_ball')

        Button(text="Stop Ball", bg='yellow',
               command=self.stop_it).grid(row=1, column=0)
        Button(text="Exit", bg='orange',
               command=self.window.quit).grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.window.after(50, self.move_the_ball)

        self.window.mainloop()

    def move_the_ball(self):
        if self.running:
            self.canvas.move('red_ball', self.deltax, self.deltay)
            if self.x1 >= 400:
               self.deltax = -2
            if self.x0 < 0:
               self.deltax = 2
            if self.y1 > 290:
                self.deltay = -3
            if self.y0 < 0:
                self.deltay = 3

            ## keep track of the coordinates to tell when
            ## the ball moves off canvas
            self.x0 += self.deltax
            self.x1 += self.deltax
            self.y0 += self.deltay
            self.y1 += self.deltay

            self.window.after(25, self.move_the_ball)

    def stop_it(self):
        self.running=False

BounceTest()
```